# Best way to animate 2d missiles in Blender

Tags: animation

I'm planning to make a fake 16-bit shoot 'em up gameplay video using models made in Blender and I was wondering what would be the best way to animate a flurry of missiles similar to the 'Itano Circus':

[image]

(Mind you, I'm a beginner at Blender, so I don't intend on creating something as grandiose as this. Just about 5-6 missles in a single firing will do)

Would I have to go about this by animating with the Grease Pencil and then apply AA or can I do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a particle system to emmit particles toward a negative force field.

Then assign a missile object to those particles.

[image]

Or you can make the particles follow boids physics and this is what I get.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a sublime way of handling that! Thanks so much. Now, how about the exhaust of each one?